# ElasticSearc - unable to get nested object from multilevel nested object

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have multilevel nested object. the first nested object is category and inside category there is one more nested object is group.
So I want to get distinct category along with nested groups using aggregation query.
am successful to get distinct category but unable to get group detail with it.

**Mapping:**

```
  "mappings": {
  "doc": {
    "properties": {
      "categories": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "cat_id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "cat_name": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "cat_slug": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "cat_type": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "groups": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "group": {
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "group_name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "id": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "ordering": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "parent_id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "parent_name": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "parent_slug": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "parent_type": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Sample data:**

```
    {
  "_index": "product",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "18556",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "sku": "GR0005P08",
    "product_id": 18556,
    "slug": "blue-garter-with-sexy-laces",
    "categories": [
      {
        "ordering": 10,
        "cat_id": 343,
        "cat_type": 1,
        "cat_slug": "t-thisr",
        "cat_name": "cat1"
      },
      {
        "ordering": 9999999,
        "cat_id": 2,
        "cat_type": 3,
        "cat_slug": "pajams",
        "cat_name": "pajams"
      },
      {
        "ordering": 5,
        "cat_id": 77,
        "cat_type": 3,
        "cat_slug": "accessories",
        "cat_name": "Accessories"
      },
      {
        "parent_name": "Pajams",
        "cat_name": "Night",
        "ordering": 1,
        "cat_id": 139,
        "parent_type": 3,
        "cat_slug": "night",
        "parent_id": 2,
        "groups": [
          {
            "id": 146,
            "group_name": "Shop By Style"
          },
          {
            "id": 481,
            "group_name": "Shop By Offer "
          }
        ],
        "parent_slug": "pajams",
        "cat_type": 1
      }
    ],
    "name": "love for pajams"
  }
}
```

**This is my aggregation query:**

```
    GET product/_search
{
  "_source": [
    "product_id"
  ],
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "categories",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "categories.cat_slug": "xyz"
              }
            }

          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "categories": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "categories"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "distinct_categories.cat_name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "categories.cat_name"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "categories.groups.group_name": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "categories.groups.group_name.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**And this is my Response:**

```
{
  "took": 11,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 8,
    "max_score": 3.232121,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "product",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "15621",
        "_score": 3.232121,
        "_source": {
          "product_id": 15621
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "product",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "18556",
        "_score": 2.5758784,
        "_source": {
          "product_id": 18556
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "categories": {
      "doc_count": 98,
      "distinct_categories.cat_name": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 2,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 50,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "Accessories",
            "doc_count": 8,
            "categories.groups.group_name": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": []
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "T-shirt",
            "doc_count": 8,
            "categories.groups.group_name": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": []
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "Sexy",
            "doc_count": 7,
            "categories.groups.group_name": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": []
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "clothing",
            "doc_count": 6,
            "categories.groups.group_name": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": []
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "Pants",
            "doc_count": 6,
            "categories.groups.group_name": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": []
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "Colour Me",
            "doc_count": 4,
            "categories.groups.group_name": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": []
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "Pajamas",
            "doc_count": 3,
            "categories.groups.group_name": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": []
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found issue with mapping definition of **groups** after changing query work fine.

```
{
"type": "nested",
"properties": {
  "group_name": {
    "type": "keyword"
  },
  "id": {
    "type": "long"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably try `"field": "categories.groups.group_name"` instead of `"field": "categories.groups.group_name.keyword"` in you deepest aggregation?

Edit:

Using `"categories.groups.group_name.keyword"` is the correct way to achieve this. The problem should be that you would need to add `nested` for each level of your nested structure for your query.

```
"aggs": {
"categories": {
  "nested": {
    "path": "categories"
  },
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_categories.cat_name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "categories.cat_name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "deeper_nested_agg": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "categories.groups"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "categories.groups.group_name": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "categories.groups.group_name.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please give it a try. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Fei, thanks for the reply.if i use ""categories.groups.group_name"" the i get error ."type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [categories.groups.group_name] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."

Comment: Hey. Sorry I did not look close enough for your question. I think you could need to add two nested in your query make your aggregation works. I have updated my answer, Please give it a try.

Comment: hello Fei , Thanks for your valuable time and effort, issue resolved problem with the mapping.